# Android Studio Farsi string

Tags: java, string, android-studio, unicode, farsi

I'm trying to add items to a Spinner :

```
private static final String[]paths = {"فارسی", "English"};

ddlFrom = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ddlFrom);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
ddlFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But the result has problems with Persian string and my spinner in device shows "?????" instead of "فارسی"

for "English" it is correct.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the **file encoding** of the file that **contains** the arabic text to **UTF-8**.

You need to check your editor/IDE settings - for Android Studio go to Settings -> Editors -> File Encodings and check files and project encoding.

This is how you change file encoding from inside [Android-Studio](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/).

Comment: Thank you, I had to restart the Android Studio after these changes.